# Avoiding duplicates while Merging two dataframes in R

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I have two dataframes that have have the same ID:

DF 1

```
ID <- c(20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25)
Town <- c("Nairobi", "Kisumu", "Mombasa", "Nairobi", "Mombasa", "Nairobi")
Name <- c("John", "Joseph", "Agnes","Steph","Brian","Jayden")
Customer <- data.frame(ID, Town, Name)
```

DF 2

```
ID <- c(20, 20,22, 22, 23, 25, 24, 20)
Town <- c("Nairobi", "Nairobi", "Mombasa", "Mombasa", "Nairobi", "Nairobi","Mombasa", "Nairobi")
Amount <- c(100, 300, 500, 400, 300, 1000, 300, 170)
TownSales <- data.frame(ID, Town, Amount)
```

I want my final Dataframe after merging to be like the one below, No duplicates in the `Name` column in DF1 because it has less rows than DF2. I'm avoiding duplicates because the dataframe I have that has less rows, contains continous variables that I'd like to compute.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is not really about removing duplicates while merging but rather how to adjust your table after the merge. Let me explain and please find below a reproducible example answering your problem.

I am using the data.table package which is very efficient for these kind of problems.

```
# Load library
library(data.table)

# Initialize dataframes
ID <- c(20, 20,22, 22, 23, 25, 24, 20)
Town <- c("Nairobi", "Nairobi", "Mombasa", "Mombasa", "Nairobi", "Nairobi","Mombasa", "Nairobi")
Amount <- c(100, 300, 500, 400, 300, 1000, 300, 170)
TownSales <- data.frame(ID, Town, Amount)

ID <- c(20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25)
Town <- c("Nairobi", "Kisumu", "Mombasa", "Nairobi", "Mombasa", "Nairobi")
Name <- c("John", "Joseph", "Agnes","Steph","Brian","Jayden")
Customer <- data.frame(ID, Town, Name)

# Perform the merge
results_dt <- merge(Customer,TownSales)
```

After these steps we end up with the following table:

| ID | Town | Name | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | Nairobi | John | 100 |
| 20 | Nairobi | John | 300 |
| 20 | Nairobi | John | 170 |
| 22 | Mombasa | Agnes | 500 |
| 22 | Mombasa | Agnes | 400 |
| 23 | Nairobi | Steph | 300 |
| 24 | Mombasa | Brian | 300 |
| 25 | Nairobi | Jayden | 1000 |

Then we just need to adjust duplicated data as expected from you, i.e for all duplicates by ID, Town and Name, we set the Name column to NA.
The below line is really what you are looking for:

```
# Adjust table for duplicated rows
results_dt[duplicated(results_dt, by = c("ID","Town","Name")),Name:=NA]
```

Finally, the results table looks like this:

| ID | Town | Name | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | Nairobi | John | 100 |
| 20 | Nairobi |  | 300 |
| 20 | Nairobi |  | 170 |
| 22 | Mombasa | Agnes | 500 |
| 22 | Mombasa |  | 400 |
| 23 | Nairobi | Steph | 300 |
| 24 | Mombasa | Brian | 300 |
| 25 | Nairobi | Jayden | 1000 |

If needed you can always rearrange the order after this.